# Generate word combinations from a list of strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, combinations

I wanted to create an algorithm in java where I can pass a list of strings and it returns a new list with all possible combinations of the strings it has in the list.

Example:

```
String[] listWords = new String[] {

                "windows",
                "linux",
                "mac",
                "10",
                "20"

        };
```

I would like to call a method by passing the list that returns all possible combinations, in all orders.

```
combinations(listWords);
```

This is the result I wanted to have:

windows,linux,mac,10,20,windowslinux,linuxwindows,windowsmac,windows10,10windows,windows20,20windows,windowslinuxmac1020,windowsmaclinux20,mac10,mac20,20mac,20mac10,windowsmac,macwindows...

I tried this:

```
public String[][] combinations (String[] ports) {
        List<String[]> combinationList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for ( long i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, ports.length); i++ ) {
            List<String> portList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for ( int j = 0; j < ports.length; j++ ) {
                if ( (i & (long) Math.pow(2, j)) > 0 ) {
                    portList.add(ports[j]);
                }
            }
            combinationList.add(portList.toArray(new String[0]));
        }
        return combinationList.toArray(new String[0][0]);
    }
```

But this returns:

[image]

This was not how I wanted it. The result had to be:

list: [windows, linux, windowslinux, linuxwindows, windows10, 10windowsmaclinux...]

Is it possible to do this in java? thank you who can help :)

Comment: By the way, a tip: `List.of( "windows",  "linux",   "mac",  "10",    "20" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, the following will solve the problem.

You can build the result iteratively starting from the list of words that you have, and in each iteration you add longer and longer words. The first iteration gives you the original list. The second iteration adds one new word to each, giving you the permutations of 2 words. The third iteration adds one new word to each of those, giving you the permutations of 3 words, and so on.

```
List<String> getWordPermutations(List<String> words) {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(words);
    List<String> oldPermutations = new ArrayList<>(words);

    for (int i = 1; i < words.size(); i++) {
        List<String> newPermutations = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String previousList : oldPermutations) {
            for (String word : words) {
                if (previousList.contains(word)) {
                    continue;
                }
                newPermutations.add(previousList + word);
            }
        }
        oldPermutations = newPermutations;
        result.addAll(newPermutations);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It worked, it's working as expected! It seems that all possible combinations with the strings are being generated. Thank you, Joni!